# How to get the captive portal's URL which I am currently connected to?

Tags: wi-fi, captive-portal

I just connected to a WiFi network which uses captive portal login page. I would like to view the captive portal's URL or IP address.

How do I do that?

I have tried clicking forget network on the WiFi in order to get the login page again, but it just connects without triggering the login screen, I think it saves the login info upon correct login.

The second thing I have tried is to wipe the cache and data of the CaptivePortal app from system settings, with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21538287/5958455), Captive Portal is triggered only when you're trying to make a request.

So the answer is: Open an arbitrary web page in your favorite browser, and you'll get redirected to the Captive Portal login page.

From my own experiences, I recommend that you visit a website that does NOT use HTTPS, as encrypted connection may interfere with the redirection (Captive Portal redirection is in fact a man-in-the-middle).

Comment: Didn't work: The browser just opens the page.

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan Try using another device or change the MAC address of your device. Such login systems recognize logged-in devices.

Comment: Finding nowadays a website that does not use HTTPS can be quite complicated. In such case you can use http://neverssl.com

Comment: Genius! I didn’t know the ssl could be a problem. Just try to open localhost and should open it

Comment: This is the correct answer for me. Explicitly typing http://google.com solves it